# How to structure WordPress plugin to display data from API

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am creating a plugin that connects to a remote API that has car listings and displays the data that's returned in that call.

The plugin essentially does not need to interact with the WordPress database at all.

I already know I can use things like `wp_remote_get`, `file_get_contents` and `file_get_contents` to retrieve that data.

My problem is that I'm not sure if I should be creating a plugin for this or just shortcodes or page-templates or what.

I want the urls to look like

```
example.com/cars/ //Cars listing results
example.com/cars/2 //Page 2 of Cars listing results
example.com/cars/?doors=4&engine=v8 //Search parameters for Cars listing results
example.com/car/1234 //Car info page 1234 is the car_id
```

I was thinking I could create pages in WordPress called `cars` and `car` and then create custom shortcodes that would hook into some functions I build to interact with the API, but for some reason that doesn't seem like the best idea to me.

Can anyone recommend a better structure for setting this up?

Comment: you could set up a file to handle the data and create the page (template but not in the wp way) and create a rewrite rule to the file. This way there is no database entry for the page. I never use shortcodes!

Comment: I ended up creating 2 page templates (`cars.php` and `car.php`) within a child-theme. There may have been a better solution, but this works for me now.